# Checkbox in silverlight + viewmodel + C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, viewmodel

I have two checkboxes A and B. I want B to be disabled when I check A. Do you know how to do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are using `MVVM` as it seems from `viewmodel` tag then simply create a `bool` property in `view model` and bind `checkbox A's` `IsChecked` with this property.

XAML

```
Checkbox IsChecked= {Binding path = IsACheckedProperty ...} //A
```

.CS

```
public bool IsACheckedProperty
{
    get
    {
       return associated var;
    }
    set
    { 
       var = val; 
       if(var)
           IsBEnabled = false;
       else
           IsBEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Now create another property IsBEnabled for disabling B once A is checked.

```
public bool IsBEnabled
{
    get
    {
       return associated var;
    }
    set
    { 
       var = val; 
       //notify view via notifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

XAML

```
Checkbox IsEnabled = {Binding path = IsBEnabled...} //B
```